# Bootstrapping of Tor takes so much time

Tags: whonix, tor-install

Currently, I'm trying to bootstrap Tor on Whonix.
The screen says as below.

Bootstrapping Tor...
Bootstrap phase: Starting
0%

However, it's been 30 minutes since this started.
Does bootstrapping Tor usually take such a long time?
Or is this only happening because of some kind of trouble on my computer?

I would appreciate it if you solve this matter for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Tor users group. It would help if you provided some more detail. Are you actually just running Tor, or are you trying to run the Tor Browser bundle. What version of either Tor, or the Tor Browser Bundle, are you using? What version of Whonix are you using? Once you've supplied that information, it will be easier to answer your question. It would also be helpful to look at, and post, the information from the Tor logs.

Comment: In my experience, it can take up to 4 hours before the Bridge propagates and read by Tor Atlas; try checking it after 4.5 hours

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [bridge](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Bridges). There is a chance that your internet service provider is blocking you. This is often the case at workplaces and universities. It really shouldn't take more than 30-60 seconds.